# add list from other list

Tags: c#, linq

add list from other list

I have two class
the first class name Response
The second class name Request

I filled The class name Request with an experimental example

I want fill ResponseItmes list name from Anotherlist list name

At the question mark

Any suitable way 
by Linq or otherwise
Thanks to all

```
     public class Response
            {
                public class Itme
                {

                    public string ItmeName { get; set; }
                    public string ItmeStartDate { get; set; }
                    public string ItmeEndDate { get; set; }
                }
                public class Responselist
                {
                    public string resultCode { get; set; }
                    public string resultText { get; set; }
                    public string Itmebalance { get; set; }
                    public string ItmeTypeName { get; set; }
                    public List<Itme> ResponseItmes { get; set; }
                }
            }


            public class Request
            {
                public class Itmelist
                {
                    public string ItmeID { get; set; }
                    public string ItmeName { get; set; }
                    public string ItmeStartDate { get; set; }
                    public string ItmeEndDate { get; set; }
                }

                public class Requestlist
                {
                    public List<Itmelist> RequestItmes { get; set; }

                }

            }



            Request.Itmelist c1 = new Request.Itmelist() {  ItmeID = "1", ItmeName = "A1", ItmeStartDate = "20190901185703",ItmeEndDate = "20190930235959" };
            Request.Itmelist c2 = new Request.Itmelist() {  ItmeID = "2", ItmeName = "A2", ItmeStartDate = "20190903181510",ItmeEndDate = "20190906235959" };
            Request.Itmelist c3 = new Request.Itmelist() {  ItmeID = "3", ItmeName = "A3", ItmeStartDate = "20190906005152",ItmeEndDate = "20191006235959" };
            Request.Itmelist c4 = new Request.Itmelist() {  ItmeID = "4", ItmeName = "A4", ItmeStartDate = "20190714181313",ItmeEndDate = "20991231235959" };


            List<Request.Requestlist> Anotherlist = new List<Request.Requestlist>()
            {
                new Request.Requestlist() { RequestItmes = new List<Request.Itmelist>() { c1, c2, c3, c4 } },

            };


            List<Response.Responselist> res = new List<Response.Responselist>();
            Responselist obj = new Responselist();

            obj.resultCode = "1";
            obj.resultText = "success";
            obj.Itmebalance = "15";
            obj.ItmeTypeName = "TT";
            obj.ResponseItmes = //??????????????????? add ResponseItmes From Anotherlist list
            res.Add(obj);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need Anotherlist? You can create `new List<Request.Itmelist>` directly and use it. It would be much simplier like this:

```
Request.Itmelist c1 = new Request.Itmelist() { ItmeID = "1", ItmeName = "A1", ItmeStartDate = "20190901185703", ItmeEndDate = "20190930235959" };
Request.Itmelist c2 = new Request.Itmelist() { ItmeID = "2", ItmeName = "A2", ItmeStartDate = "20190903181510", ItmeEndDate = "20190906235959" };
Request.Itmelist c3 = new Request.Itmelist() { ItmeID = "3", ItmeName = "A3", ItmeStartDate = "20190906005152", ItmeEndDate = "20191006235959" };
Request.Itmelist c4 = new Request.Itmelist() { ItmeID = "4", ItmeName = "A4", ItmeStartDate = "20190714181313", ItmeEndDate = "20991231235959" };


var requestTimes = new List<Request.Itmelist>() { c1, c2, c3, c4 };


List<Response.Responselist> res = new List<Response.Responselist>();
Responselist obj = new Responselist();

obj.resultCode = "1";
obj.resultText = "success";
obj.Itmebalance = "15";
obj.ItmeTypeName = "TT";
obj.ResponseItmes = requestTimes.Select(i => new Itme
{
    ItmeEndDate = i.ItmeEndDate,
    ItmeName = i.ItmeName,
    ItmeStartDate = i.ItmeStartDate
}).ToList();


res.Add(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SelectMany` to get all the lists and then map to the right object with `Select`

```
obj.ResponseItmes = Anotherlist.SelectMany(x => x.RequestItmes).Select(x => new Response.Itme ()
{
    //TODO: Map code here
}).ToList();
```